# optimizing query for slow queries

Tags: mysql, performance, amazon-rds, optimization, query-performance

I have this query in my slowqueries table which essentially is taking about 5-8 seconds to complete the query time:

```
SELECT s0_.id AS id0, s0_.updated AS updated1, 
       s0_.created AS created2, 
       s0_.deletedAt AS deletedAt3, 
       s0_.checked AS checked4, 
       s0_.mediaid AS mediaid5, 
       s0_.numberoflikes AS numberoflikes6, 
       s0_.numberofdislikes AS numberofdislikes7, 
       s0_.numberofcomments AS numberofcomments8, 
       s0_.createdtimestamp AS createdtimestamp9, 
       s0_.caption AS caption10, 
       s0_.captionOriginal AS captionOriginal11, 
       s0_.price AS price12, 
       s0_.link AS link13, 
       s0_.lowresimageurl AS lowresimageurl14, 
       s0_.highresimageurl AS highresimageurl15, 
       s0_.medresimageurl AS medresimageurl16, 
       s0_.isLocked AS isLocked17, 
       s0_.isShown AS isShown18, 
       s0_.isStyleInspiration AS isStyleInspiration19, 
       s0_.color AS color20, 
       s0_.viewed AS viewed21, 
       s0_.viewed_today AS viewed_today22, 
       s0_.shop_id AS shop_id23 
FROM app_instagram_shop_picture s0_ 
LEFT JOIN app_instagram_shop s1_ 
ON s0_.shop_id = s1_.id AND (s1_.deletedAt IS NULL) 
WHERE 
  (s0_.isShown = 1 AND 
   s0_.isStyleInspiration = 0 AND 
   s1_.id <> 24576 AND 
   s0_.id <> '513385.25' AND 
   s1_.isLocked = 1 AND 
   s0_.isLocked = 0 AND 
   s0_.id >= '513385.25') AND 
  (s0_.deletedAt IS NULL) 
ORDER BY s0_.updated DESC LIMIT 16;
```

I wonder what is the best way to optimize this query? I have been using percona toolkit and here's the output for this particular query.

```
# Query 1: 0.01 QPS, 0.03x concurrency, ID 0xFFE8DDA58E282913 at byte 3405997
# This item is included in the report because it matches --limit.
# Scores: V/M = 88.37
# Time range: 2014-11-07 06:32:19 to 2014-11-11 16:21:47
# Attribute    pct   total     min     max     avg     95%  stddev  median
# ============ === ======= ======= ======= ======= ======= ======= =======
# Count         14    4888
# Exec time     48  13015s      1s    566s      3s      3s     15s      1s
# Lock time      8   664ms    64us    29ms   135us   167us   445us   119us
# Rows sent     11  75.92k       0      16   15.91   15.25    1.17   15.25
# Rows examine  70   7.58G       0   2.54M   1.59M   1.61M 173.18k   1.53M
# Query size    10   5.21M   1.07k   1.09k   1.09k   1.09k   10.50   1.09k
# String:
# Databases    AppDirectory
# Hosts        localhost
# Users        root
# Query_time distribution
#   1us
#  10us
# 100us
#   1ms
#  10ms
# 100ms
#    1s  ################################################################
#  10s+  #
# Tables
#    SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM `AppDirectory` LIKE 'App_instagram_shop_picture'\G
#    SHOW CREATE TABLE `AppDirectory`.`App_instagram_shop_picture`\G
#    SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM `AppDirectory` LIKE 'App_instagram_shop'\G
#    SHOW CREATE TABLE `AppDirectory`.`App_instagram_shop`\G
# EXPLAIN /*!50100 PARTITIONS*/
SELECT s0_.id AS id0, s0_.updated AS updated1, s0_.created AS created2, s0_.deletedAt AS deletedAt3, s0_.checked AS checked4, s0_.mediaid AS mediaid5, s0_.numberoflikes AS numberoflikes6, s0_.numberofdislikes AS numberofdislikes7, s0_.numberofcomments AS numberofcomments8, s0_.createdtimestamp AS createdtimestamp9, s0_.caption AS caption10, s0_.captionOriginal AS captionOriginal11, s0_.price AS price12, s0_.link AS link13, s0_.lowresimageurl AS lowresimageurl14, s0_.highresimageurl AS highresimageurl15, s0_.medresimageurl AS medresimageurl16, s0_.isLocked AS isLocked17, s0_.isShown AS isShown18, s0_.isStyleInspiration AS isStyleInspiration19, s0_.color AS color20, s0_.viewed AS viewed21, s0_.viewed_today AS viewed_today22, s0_.shop_id AS shop_id23 FROM App_instagram_shop_picture s0_ LEFT JOIN App_instagram_shop s1_ ON s0_.shop_id = s1_.id AND (s1_.deletedAt IS NULL) WHERE (s0_.isShown = 1 AND s0_.isStyleInspiration = 0 AND s1_.id <> 25496 AND s0_.id <> '530649.5' AND s1_.isLocked = 1 AND s0_.isLocked = 0 AND s0_.id >= '530649.5') AND (s0_.deletedAt IS NULL) ORDER BY s0_.updated DESC LIMIT 16\G
```

Here's the EXPLAIN statement for the query above:

```
+----+-------------+-------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+---------+-----------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys                                                                | key                  | key_len | ref                   | rows | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+---------+-----------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | s4_   | const  | PRIMARY                                                                      | PRIMARY              | 4       | const                 |    1 | Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | s1_   | ref    | PRIMARY,shop_shown_style_deleted_idx,idx_locked_deletedAt,idx_deleted_shopId | idx_locked_deletedAt | 7       | const,const           |   37 | Using where; Using index                     |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | s3_   | ref    | IDX_9AC480D6EE45BDBF,IDX_9AC480D6683813E0                                    | IDX_9AC480D6EE45BDBF | 4       | Shopious.s1_.id       |    1 | Using where                                  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | s2_   | ref    | IDX_2F40D95EEE45BDBF,IDX_2F40D95EBACD6074                                    | IDX_2F40D95EEE45BDBF | 4       | Shopious.s1_.id       |    1 | Using where                                  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | s0_   | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                      | PRIMARY              | 4       | Shopious.s2_.style_id |    1 | NULL                                         |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+---------+-----------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
```

SHOW TABLE STATUS

```
+-----------------------------------------------+--------+---------+------------+----------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+-------------+------------+--------------------+----------+----------------+---------+
| Name                                          | Engine | Version | Row_format | Rows     | Avg_row_length | Data_length | Max_data_length | Index_length | Data_free | Auto_increment | Create_time         | Update_time | Check_time | Collation          | Checksum | Create_options | Comment |
+-----------------------------------------------+--------+---------+------------+----------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+-------------+------------+--------------------+----------+----------------+---------+
| accepted_city                        | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |        0 |              0 |       16384 |               0 |            0 |         0 |              1 | 2015-01-18 00:49:18 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8_unicode_ci    |     NULL |                |         |
| board                                | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |      123 |           1864 |      229376 |               0 |            0 |         0 |            128 | 2015-01-18 00:49:18 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8_unicode_ci    |     NULL |                |         |
| contact_type                         | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |        6 |           2730 |       16384 |               0 |            0 |         0 |              7 | 2015-01-18 00:49:18 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8_unicode_ci    |     NULL |                |         |
| guest                                | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |        0 |              0 |       16384 |               0 |        16384 |         0 |              1 | 2015-01-18 00:49:18 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8_unicode_ci    |     NULL |                |         |
| inbox                                | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |        8 |           2048 |       16384 |               0 |        16384 |         0 |             22 | 2015-01-18 00:49:18 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8_unicode_ci    |     NULL |                |         |
| inbox_message                        | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |        0 |              0 |       16384 |               0 |        32768 |         0 |           NULL | 2015-01-18 00:49:18 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8_unicode_ci    |     NULL |                |         |
| instagram_first_level_category       | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |       27 |           2427 |       65536 |               0 |        16384 |         0 |             47 | 2015-01-18 00:49:18 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8_unicode_ci    |     NULL |                |         |
| instagram_item_viewer                | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |  9708750 |             38 |   377307136 |               0 |    395804672 |   5242880 |       13423064 | 2015-01-18 00:49:18 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8_unicode_ci    |     NULL |                |         |
| instagram_picture_board              | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |     1395 |             46 |       65536 |               0 |        98304 |         0 |           1932 | 2015-01-18 00:52:39 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8_unicode_ci    |     NULL |                |         |
| instagram_picture_category           | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |   403122 |             45 |    18366464 |               0 |     31145984 |   5242880 |        1731917 | 2015-01-18 00:52:39 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8_unicode_ci    |     NULL |                |         |
| instagram_picture_failed_to_load     | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |    77687 |            101 |     7880704 |               0 |      2555904 |   4194304 |         192300 | 2015-01-18 00:52:48 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8_unicode_ci    |     NULL |                |         |
| instagram_picture_style              | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |    69623 |             37 |     2637824 |               0 |      5275648 |   4194304 |         156148 | 2015-01-18 00:52:51 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8_unicode_ci    |     NULL |                |         |
| instagram_picture_tag                | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    | 14875477 |             34 |   512720896 |               0 |    627834880 |   8388608 |       26998313 | 2015-02-15 04:19:22 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8_unicode_ci    |     NULL |                |         |
| instagram_prospective_buyer_category | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |        0 |              0 |       16384 |               0 |        49152 |         0 |              1 | 2015-01-18 00:58:08 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8_unicode_ci    |     NULL |                |         |
| instagram_second_level_category      | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |      101 |           1135 |      114688 |               0 |        16384 |         0 |            115 | 2015-01-18 00:58:08 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8_unicode_ci    |     NULL |                |         |
| instagram_shop                       | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |    30834 |            459 |    14172160 |               0 |      3407872 |   4194304 |          33870 | 2015-01-18 00:58:08 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |     NULL |                |         |
| instagram_shop_category              | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |     2213 |             51 |      114688 |               0 |       180224 |         0 |           3352 | 2015-01-18 00:58:12 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8_unicode_ci    |     NULL |                |         |
| instagram_shop_contact               | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |    31616 |             83 |     2637824 |               0 |      1589248 |   4194304 |          31738 | 2015-02-09 02:12:00 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8_unicode_ci    |     NULL |                |         |
| instagram_shop_following             | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |        0 |              0 |       16384 |               0 |        32768 |         0 |              1 | 2015-01-18 00:58:14 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8_unicode_ci    |     NULL |                |         |
| instagram_shop_picture               | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |  1351675 |            851 |  1150287872 |               0 |    255197184 |  11534336 |        2866818 | 2015-02-15 02:57:11 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8_unicode_ci    |     NULL |                |         |
| instagram_shop_picture_metadata      | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |    54188 |             48 |     2637824 |               0 |      1589248 |   4194304 |          58817 | 2015-02-09 02:11:54 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8_unicode_ci    |     NULL |                |         |
| instagram_shop_viewer                | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |   921529 |             38 |    35192832 |               0 |     47284224 |   5242880 |        1087385 | 2015-01-18 01:01:58 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8_unicode_ci    |     NULL |                |         |
| instagram_tag                        | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |   488506 |            130 |    63520768 |               0 |    116604928 |  48234496 |        1562800 | 2015-02-17 10:15:21 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8_unicode_ci    |     NULL |                |         |
| instagram_top_category               | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |        5 |           3276 |       16384 |               0 |            0 |         0 |              6 | 2015-01-18 01:02:29 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8_unicode_ci    |     NULL |                |         |
| item_comment                         | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |     3833 |             94 |      360448 |               0 |       163840 |         0 |          21520 | 2015-01-18 01:02:30 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8_unicode_ci    |     NULL |                |         |
| itemdislike                          | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |      275 |             59 |       16384 |               0 |        32768 |         0 |           1656 | 2015-01-18 01:02:30 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8_unicode_ci    |     NULL |                |         |
| itemlike                             | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |     3198 |             46 |      147456 |               0 |       262144 |         0 |          22448 | 2015-01-18 01:02:30 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8_unicode_ci    |     NULL |                |         |
| location                             | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |    42542 |             62 |     2637824 |               0 |      1589248 |   4194304 |          50757 | 2015-01-18 01:02:30 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8_unicode_ci    |     NULL |                |         |
| location_city                        | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |     5602 |             55 |      311296 |               0 |       147456 |         0 |           5603 | 2015-01-18 01:02:32 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8_unicode_ci    |     NULL |                |         |
| location_province                    | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |       32 |            512 |       16384 |               0 |            0 |         0 |             33 | 2015-01-18 01:02:32 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8_unicode_ci    |     NULL |                |         |
| location_state                       | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |      466 |            105 |       49152 |               0 |        16384 |         0 |            546 | 2015-01-18 01:02:32 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8_unicode_ci    |     NULL |                |         |
| message                              | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |        0 |              0 |       16384 |               0 |        32768 |         0 |              1 | 2015-01-18 01:02:32 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8_unicode_ci    |     NULL |                |         |
| message_metadata                     | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |        0 |              0 |       16384 |               0 |        32768 |         0 |              1 | 2015-01-18 01:02:32 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8_unicode_ci    |     NULL |                |         |
| pack_type                            | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |        4 |           4096 |       16384 |               0 |            0 |         0 |              5 | 2015-01-18 01:02:32 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8_unicode_ci    |     NULL |                |         |
| payment_method                       | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |        2 |           8192 |       16384 |               0 |            0 |         0 |              3 | 2015-01-18 01:02:33 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8_unicode_ci    |     NULL |                |         |
| picture_renamer                      | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |   132261 |             43 |     5783552 |               0 |      6324224 |   4194304 |         187620 | 2015-01-18 01:02:33 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8_unicode_ci    |     NULL |                |         |
| preferred_contact_type               | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |     1039 |             63 |       65536 |               0 |        32768 |         0 |           1282 | 2015-01-18 01:02:36 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8_unicode_ci    |     NULL |                |         |
| price_range                          | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |        0 |              0 |       16384 |               0 |            0 |         0 |              1 | 2015-01-18 01:02:36 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8_unicode_ci    |     NULL |                |         |
| profile_picture                      | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |    32880 |            144 |     4734976 |               0 |       507904 |   4194304 |          37148 | 2015-01-18 01:02:36 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8_unicode_ci    |     NULL |                |         |
| prospective_buyer                    | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |        0 |              0 |       16384 |               0 |            0 |         0 |              1 | 2015-01-18 01:02:38 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8_unicode_ci    |     NULL |                |         |
| prospective_organic_shop             | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |     1840 |             71 |      131072 |               0 |            0 |         0 |           2054 | 2015-01-18 01:02:38 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8_unicode_ci    |     NULL |                |         |
| prospective_shop                     | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |   190504 |            173 |    33095680 |               0 |     13156352 |   7340032 |         201721 | 2015-01-18 01:02:38 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8_unicode_ci    |     NULL |                |         |
| prospective_shop_status              | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |        3 |           5461 |       16384 |               0 |            0 |         0 |              4 | 2015-01-18 01:02:49 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8_unicode_ci    |     NULL |                |         |
| receipt                              | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |     5701 |             68 |      393216 |               0 |       458752 |         0 |           6585 | 2015-01-18 01:02:49 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8_unicode_ci    |     NULL |                |         |
| shipping_cost                        | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |        0 |              0 |       16384 |               0 |            0 |         0 |              1 | 2015-01-18 01:02:49 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8_unicode_ci    |     NULL |                |         |
| shipping_cost_express                | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |     5711 |             80 |      458752 |               0 |            0 |         0 |           5553 | 2015-01-18 01:02:49 | NULL        | NULL       | latin1_swedish_ci  |     NULL |                |         |
| shipping_info                        | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |        0 |              0 |       16384 |               0 |        32768 |         0 |              1 | 2015-01-18 01:02:50 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8_unicode_ci    |     NULL |                |         |
| source                               | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |        6 |           2730 |       16384 |               0 |            0 |         0 |              7 | 2015-01-18 01:02:50 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8_unicode_ci    |     NULL |                |         |
| style                                | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |      126 |           1690 |      212992 |               0 |            0 |         0 |            143 | 2015-01-18 01:02:50 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8_unicode_ci    |     NULL |                |         |
| tag                                  | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |     2200 |             52 |      114688 |               0 |            0 |         0 |           2255 | 2015-01-18 01:02:50 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8_unicode_ci    |     NULL |                |         |
| thread                               | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |        0 |              0 |       16384 |               0 |        16384 |         0 |              1 | 2015-01-18 01:02:51 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8_unicode_ci    |     NULL |                |         |
| thread_metadata                      | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |        0 |              0 |       16384 |               0 |        32768 |         0 |              1 | 2015-01-18 01:02:51 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8_unicode_ci    |     NULL |                |         |
| transaction                          | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |     6512 |            244 |     1589248 |               0 |       606208 |   4194304 |           8449 | 2015-01-18 01:02:51 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8_unicode_ci    |     NULL |                |         |
| user                                 | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |    32047 |            344 |    11026432 |               0 |      6258688 |   4194304 |          35599 | 2015-01-18 01:02:52 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8_unicode_ci    |     NULL |                |         |
| user_follow_user                     | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |       17 |            963 |       16384 |               0 |        32768 |         0 |           NULL | 2015-01-18 01:02:56 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8_unicode_ci    |     NULL |                |         |
| viewer                               | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |   360950 |             56 |    20496384 |               0 |     19988480 |   7340032 |         397608 | 2015-01-18 01:02:56 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8_unicode_ci    |     NULL |                |         |
| transmission                                  | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |        0 |              0 |       16384 |               0 |            0 |         0 |              1 | 2015-01-18 01:03:07 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8_unicode_ci    |     NULL |                |         |
+-----------------------------------------------+--------+---------+------------+----------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+-------------+------------+--------------------+----------+----------------+---------+
```

SHOW CREATE TABLE style;

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table          | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      |

```
+----------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| style | CREATE TABLE `style` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `style` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `styleTitle` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `styleTitleDescription` varchar(500) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `styleDescription` varchar(5120) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `coverUrl` varchar(1000) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `selected_at_home` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `smallCoverUrl` varchar(1000) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `styleFontCustom` varchar(1000) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `styleTitleColor` varchar(1000) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=143 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci |
+----------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: The best way is to look at execution plans and add indexes where needed.

Comment: @adit If you want us to help, you need to provide the output of everything that is commented at the last portion of `pt-query-digest`, all the `SHOW TABLE STATUS`, all the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and the `EXPLAIN SELECT`. If not, we are just guessing. Even that may no be enough.

Comment: @jynus I added the explain statement above, I can't do pt-query-digest since this is on an rds machine

Answer (score 0):

Indexes are usually the best way to increase the speed in any query, but there are other alternatives that might help:

1) Check if the field you are joining the tables are INTEGERS instead of CHAR/VARCHAR. In your case would be s0_.shop_id = s1_.id. Replace them by INTEGERS if possible, that reduces the time to join the table during the query.

2) The field s0_.id seems to be a CHAR/VARCHAR, but looks like you are storing float/double values on it. Change the field type to float/double.

3) Depending on what database you are using (Oracle, Mysql, Postgre, ...) it might have an embedded cache system. Even if it doesn't have, you can use Memcache or Redis.